# Datatables - On click from image

Tags: laravel-5, datatables, render

I have a datatable populated by 4 fields via a Laravel route. That is fine and works great.

Additionally I have added 2 columns with icons, again that is fine. One is to show a sliding panel of information and one will be a link to more details.

I show these by rendering column info.

I wish to have an onlick event for one which will use the data in column 0 which is a key field. I have tried:

```
{
  "targets": [4], 
  "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            {return '<div align="center"><a href="#"><img src="{{ asset("siteicons/Info_Box_Blue.png") }}" id="trigger" onclick="ShowSlider( {{ ' + 0 + '}} )"></a></div>';}    
                                }
                    },
```

This is in the columnDefs, but clicking does not do anything - even if I put a simple alert.

Help, please!

Comment: Is your HTML correct? What do you see when you inspect the element? Also, are you repeating IDs? I hope not as these should be unique. What library are you using for ShowSlider?

Comment: The HTML is correct but obviously it is something wrong with my syntax as when I inspect I get

`<img src="http://localhost:8000/siteicons/Info_Box_Blue.png" id="trigger" onclick="ShowSlider(  + 0 +  )">'

The 0 should be a value of column zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
    return '<div align="center"><a href="#"><img src="{{ asset("siteicons/Info_Box_Blue.png") }}" id="trigger" onclick="ShowSlider(' + full[0] + ')"></a></div>';   
}
```

If you're trying to get data from the row add it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Extra curly braces are there in your render function. Could u please remove and try it ?

```
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<div align="center"><a href="#"><img src="{{ asset("siteicons/Info_Box_Blue.png") }}" id="trigger" onclick="ShowSlider(0)"></a></div>';   
                                }
```

Comment: I removed them but the 0 should be the value of column 0. Debugging is showing ShowSlider as not defined but it is a little later.